# Telnet server echo option leads to unwanted whitespace

Tags: rust, telnet

I'm building a telnet server in Rust. I want the server to be able to display text files and respond to custom single-character commands that are sent from the client. The user should be able to just press a key and have the server respond-- they shouldn't see their input, so I'm using the telnet ECHO option so that the client does not display the user's input.
However, after I send the echo option, whenever I print a file or some string, extra whitespace is inserted.

I've condensed the code to isolate the problem:

file: main.rs

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:4321")?;

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream?;

        let contents = fs::read_to_string("file.txt")
            .expect("Couldn't find file.");

        // This array is [255, 251, 01]
        stream.write(&[IAC.byte(), WILL.byte(), Echo.byte()])?;
        stream.write(contents.as_bytes())?;
        // This array is [255, 252, 01]
        stream.write(&[IAC.byte(), WONT.byte(), Echo.byte()])?;
        stream.write(contents.as_bytes())?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

file: file.txt

```
Hello
This
Is
A
File.
```

When I run this and connect locally via telnet:

```
celie:~$ telnet localhost 4321
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello
     This
         Is
           A
            File.
                 Hello
This
Is
A
File.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I can rearrange when I write the telnet codes to the stream, and I've used other telnet options and gotten valid responses back from the client, but as soon as I say "WILL Echo", all subsequent output gets all this extra whitespace, until I say "WONT Echo".

I want the file to simply display as normal with no whitespace added after newlines, which works when I don't use the echo option, even if I use other telnet options.

The whitespace doesn't seem like it should be related to the echo option at all! Any telnet insights are appreciated!

Comment: I know people use telnet to test plaintext TCP protocols, but in this case I think telnet is just adding confusing over e.g. plain netcat (on Mac you can probably get it with homebrew). On Windows, there is a `ncat` binary in the distribution you get from ncat.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is roughly the same as "raw mode" on a local terminal (which applications use to disable echo and line editing and handle input themselves) — in this situation, the server/application is responsible for sending *two* control characters at the end of the line, whereas ordinarily the OS kernel does this for you.

You must send a carriage return (`"\r"`), which moves the cursor *left*, and a line feed (`"\n"`), which moves the cursor *down.* You're sending only line feeds (as is conventional for modern text files), so the cursor moves down but not left. If you had sent a longer file, you would have noticed that text would wrap around the right edge but always start a new line below the end of the previous one.

As you copy the text to the TCP stream, you must check for line feeds and insert the necessary carriage returns.